# app works on development google-play store show device incompatible

Tags: android, device, google-play, incompatibility

I'm developing a android app. While developing I tested it on Moto E os-4.4.4. It works properly. But after deployment playstore shows your device is incompatible with this version. It shows compatible with many other devices running same os version.
I found some similar questions I tried there answers but nothing seems to work for me.
Any help is appreciated.

Here's my manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:maxSdkVersion="18" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Not only moto e, its showing incompatible with over 1000 devices. The external libraries I've used are apptentive,flurry,facebook and actionbarshelock.

Comment: Do you have any uses-feature or screen compatibility sections?

Comment: No uses-feature or screen compatibility sections

Comment: Is this problem solved? I'm also facing this issue with my app...

Comment: There was some problem with playstore. It got solved automatically after few days

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.4 is version 19.  By setting a max SDK version, you're telling it not to allow install on any version over 18.  So it won't consider your device compatible.  Remove that max sdk version.  Even google no longer checks this on the device beyond version 2.0.1.

Comment: I get the same incompatiblity error even after removing it.Also Beginning with Android 4.4, the platform no longer requires that your app acquire the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when you need to access only your app-specific regions of the external storage using the methods above. However, the permissions are required if you want to access the shareable regions of the external storage, provided by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with google-playstore. It got solved after playstore update and now it's compatible with my device as it should be.